# mod_rewrite with optional email and filename parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

There are 3 points I need to pull from a clean url and convert them to url parameters.  A typical clean url looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/page/someAlphaNumeric-OR-emailAddress/file.html
```

or:

```
http://mysite.com/page/file.html
```

or:

```
http://mysite.com/page/someAlphaNumeric-OR-emailAddress
```

The first variable will always be alphanumeric, the second is optional and may contain either alphanumeric or an email address, and the third (also optional if the email/alphanumeric is supplied) will always be a filename.

I've tried a number of different things for the second variable, but the problem is it seems the file and the email address fight.
The code which seems closest to the solution so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/.*$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&file=$0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/.*$ index.php?page=$1&file=$0 [L,QSA]
```

If I supply a page, and both email address and the file name, only the file name gets assigned a parameter.  Without the file in the url, the email address gets plopped into the file parameter.

Of course if I supply a page, alphanumeric, and file, everything works perfectly.  The conditions could probably be set above all the rules, but I am not sure.

Comment: For the 2nd and 3rd example URLs, what's the difference in patterns between `file.html` and `someAlphaNumeric-OR-emailAddress`? Does the file always have a `.html` extension? Otherwise there's no way to tell whether this is a file or id.

Comment: The file can be any file at all, with any extension, though for the most part they will be common website extensions.  The ID on the other hand must contain a @ in order to be an email address, of course.  Otherwise, if there is no @ (not an email address) it will be strictly alphanumeric.  Never any punctuation or symbols.

Comment: So in other words, there's no difference in the pattern and there can't be a regex to tell them apart? Then you need to determine the difference programmatically in `index.php`.

Comment: The presence of a @ symbol would indicate that it is an email address, not a file.  A file would contain a `.` but not a @, and an alphanumeric would only contain numbers and letters.

Comment: SO if there isn't a @ it is 100% a file? Because you have **someAlphaNumeric-OR-emailAddress**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think should go in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# /page
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# /page/file.html
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([\w.-]+\.[a-z]{3,4})$ index.php?page=$1&file=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# /page/id OR /page/email
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+|[\w.-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

# /page/id/file.html OR /page/email/file.html
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+|[\w.-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+\.[a-z]{3,4})$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&file=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The above rules redirect

```
/mailbox --> /index.php?page=mailbox
/mailbox/login.php --> /index.php?page=mailbox&file=login.php

/mailbox/SuperJer123 --> /index.php?page=mailbox&id=SuperJer123
/mailbox/superjer@so.com --> /index.php?page=mailbox&id=superjer@so.com

/mailbox/superjer@so.com/inbox.php
                   --> /index.php?page=mailbox&id=superjer@so.com&file=inbox.php
```

Note that if you don't want redirection when the file/directory exists; you need to append below to all of the rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: It works like a charm, with one modification.  The resulting url should be `index.php?page=$1` rather than `index.php/page=$1`.  I do have need of the access to actual files, so the conditions have been added to each rule.